# Import and Link image texture to an Active Shader Node in Python

Tags: import, image, linked-data, shader-nodes

I'm working on a part of an Addon that create a **New Principled BSDF** shader then a **ShaderNodeTexImage** (make it **active**), import an image **with File brother** and **link** it to the **ShaderNodeTexImage**.

Everything works except for the last step  link it to the ShaderNodeTexImage
`Texture_Node.image = ('img.name')`

How can I tell blender get the name of the last image imported?

I've tried to create Lists before and after importing image and compare them to reach the new picture imported, but the command `Texture_Node.image` expect a string not a list or a set.
and O'm sure there is a better way to reach the name of the last picture imported.

```
import bpy


material_bascic = bpy.data.materials.new(name= "New Mat")
material_bascic.use_nodes = True

bpy.context.object.active_material = material_bascic

principled_node = material_bascic.node_tree.nodes.get('Principled BSDF')

Texture_Node = material_bascic.node_tree.nodes.new('ShaderNodeTexImage')
Texture_Node.location = (-300,215)

material_bascic.node_tree.links.new(Texture_Node.outputs[0],principled_node.inputs[0])

nodes = material_bascic.node_tree.nodes
for node in nodes:
    node.select = False
    
Texture_Node.select = True
nodes.active = Texture_Node

bpy.ops.image.open('INVOKE_DEFAULT')

#Texture_Node.image = img
```

Answer (score 0):

The usual technique for finding the last thing created by a bpy op works here. In this case you want `bpy.data.images[-1]`.

This works because bpy ops that create things usually add them as the last item on the `bpy.data` structure that's relevant, in this case, the `image` structure and `[-1]` is a Python idiom for finding the last element.

```py
import bpy


material_bascic = bpy.data.materials.new(name= "New Mat")
material_bascic.use_nodes = True

bpy.context.object.active_material = material_bascic

principled_node = material_bascic.node_tree.nodes.get('Principled BSDF')

Texture_Node = material_bascic.node_tree.nodes.new('ShaderNodeTexImage')
Texture_Node.location = (-300,215)

material_bascic.node_tree.links.new(Texture_Node.outputs[0],principled_node.inputs[0])

nodes = material_bascic.node_tree.nodes
for node in nodes:
    node.select = False
    
Texture_Node.select = True
nodes.active = Texture_Node

bpy.ops.image.open('INVOKE_DEFAULT')

Texture_Node.image = bpy.data.images[-1]
```

Comment: Hi @Marty, thanks for your Answer. I have tried with '''bpy.data.images[-1]''', but it returns the last sorted list by name and not the last imported data. if I import B.jpg then A.jpg, '''bpy.data.images[-1]''' returns  B.jpg. Did I miss something or is there any other command to do it? Bests

Comment: Ooops.  I should have checked more carefully.  You're right, images is maintained sorted.  When I get a few minutes I'll figure out to find the most recently read image.  Sorry for misleading.